# delete files who's filenames match string

Tags: python

I have mucked things up when trying to make a script to copy and rename files. I have ended up copying files into the same directory that the file existed. I wanted to copy and rename the files and add to a new directory. I now need to delete files which contain a certain string located in various places within the filename. I am able to print these files with the below code, but unable to delete them. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import os
import shutil as sh
from pathlib import Path
from pathlib import PurePath

root_path = PurePath("/Users/codychandler/SyncDrive/Colocation Information(Kory.Williams@charter.com )")
#dest_path = PurePath(r"/Users/codychandler/Docs/MSA_SO Crawl2")

exts = [".pdf", ".doc", ".docx"]
str = "Kory.Williams"

for root, _, fnames in os.walk(root_path):
for f in fnames:
    if f.endswith(tuple(exts)) and str in f:
        f = os.path.abspath(f)
        print (f)
        os.remove(os.path.join(root,f))
```

EDIT:

This code returns the following:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Comment: classic mistake: `os.remove(f)` should be `os.remove(os.path.join(root,f))`

Comment: This code returns the following: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`

Comment: remove the abspath part. it prepends the current directory (where the file is _not_) and makes `os.path.join` inefficient